# Xib y .swift - ¿Cual instancio?

Tags: swift

Como dice la pregunta, si tengo 2 archivos: un `.xib` (que es una vista) y un `.swift`, que corresponde a esa vista. ¿Cual de los dos se instancia? En otras palabras, ¿Quien llama a quien?.

Answer (score 1):

Has de tener claro que estrictamente hablando solo se instancian las clases. Un archivo `.XIB` no es más que un `xml` que relaciona unas propiedades con una clase para poder acceder a ellas.

Después, un archivo con la extensión `.swift` no es mas que un archivo de texto, que puede contener o no la declaración de una clase. O dicho de otra forma, no por tener un archivo `.swift` podrás "instanciar" ese archivo, porque puede contener simplemente estructuras que no vas a poder instanciar de ninguna manera.

Por último, lo más habitual es que instancies un `UIViewController` el cuál tiene un método inicializador al que le pasas como parámetro el `.XIB` correspondiente para "casar" ambos archivos.

Comment: Genial, gracias 

Comment: De nada, cualquier otra duda ya sabes...

Comment: Mhergon ahora tengo problemas con un UIView y su xib...estoy odiando esto uhh

Comment: Si solo instancia la clase...porque enlazó el .xib al controllers mediante el storyboard y no mediante el objeto controlador?

Comment: Te estás liando. El XIB no es es más que un XML auxiliar para poder "dibujar" la interfaz de forma más simple sin tener que picar todo el código. No le des más vueltas, se hace así y ya está.